# Handle validator to return json

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Laravel throw an exception at `$validator->fails()` call.

Ok, I just want to create a stateless register method in `ApiController.php` with Laravel `5.7`.

I used the `Validator` facade to check the sent data.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails())  {
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 
                                           Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
```

But, when I use xdebug, I see something strange. The fails methods seems throw an exception.

Laravel send an error HTML page with title:

> Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters.

The route is used in `api.php`

```
Route::post('register', 'Api\UserController@register');
```

Do you have an explanation for this?
Thx for reading.

Comment: use $validator->validate() instead of $validator->fails()

Comment: the unique requires a parameter like unique:user when u are using the user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for unique rule is `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`.
So i changed it for you to use the `users` table.
If you don't want to use the users table change the `users` part behind `unique:`

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
]);
if ($validator->fails())  {
    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 
        Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

For more information on the unique rule see this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique

Comment: ah i'm feel so bad to have forgotten this ! Thx !

Answer (score 0):

In your API request add the following header:

```php
...
Accept: application/json // <-----
```

This will tell Laravel that you want a response in a json format.

---

Note: this is different to the `Content-type: application/json`. The later indicates the format of the data tha is being sent in the body.

Comment: Isn't `response()->json()` already making sure the response is always in json format headers included?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, when using Xdebug for testing, in case the validation fails it will throw the exception even before to reach that statement. Try it figure it out if it works :) If not, we keep digging.

Comment: The exception clearly states 'Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters.' i think he should add the table where email should be unique Like i explained in my answer. That will solve the exception and from there on it should work just fine.

Comment: yes, i can have json format using Accept keyword in http header request, but if i start my laravel app in production mode, laravel will not show any exception error normaly ?

Comment: @Mazimilien when you change your `APP_DEBUG` key in your `.env` to `false` (and also adapt the `APP_LOG_LEVEL` and `APP_ENV`) it will show just a regular error message